# Git remote is ahead by one commit that I can't fetch locally or reset

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-reset

After some rebasing and hard resets I ended up with a commit in my repository that I can't track locally.

My repository on bitbucket looks like this

[image]

While the last commit on my local repository is `a255675`. I'm trying to revert the remote head to `a255675` by doing:

```
 git reset --hard a255675
 git push -f origin master
```

But the response is :

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Doing a `git fetch origin` followed by a `git reset --hard origin/master` gives this response:

```
HEAD is now at a255675
```

Commits `a255675` and `25b290e` are in fact identical in terms of changes and essentially I just want to reset the remote head to `a255675`.

Why doesn't it work and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the tag at "25b290e commit" is required?

Comment: @rajuGT No it is not

Comment: Okay, then try deleting and repeat the steps you mentioned.

Comment: Also, you are saying both commits are identical.  Is commit 25b290e is merge commit by git?

Comment: @rajuGT I didn't even need to repeat the steps, just doing  `git push origin :0.2.9` got rid of the tag **and** the commit! Thank you, you may want to post it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the git-tag 0.2.9 which is ahead of your current local commit

```
   git push origin :0.2.9
```

It will resolve the issue.